# How to solve timed out error when using requests with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I was trying to scrape a website using BeautifulSoup and Requests. The problem I am facing is that I get a few results back and then the program hangs indefinitely. Then, I tried using the `timeout` function and it returned an error. Here is the code I am using:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
all_data=[]
for i in range(1950,2020):
    x = requests.get("https://indiankanoon.org/browse/supremecourt/%s/"%(i), timeout = 5)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(x.content, 'html.parser')
    data = [x["href"] for x in soup.find_all('a',{'href': re.compile(r'/search/')})]
    all_data.append(data)
```

I have tried using `headers` in `requests.get()` but that has not solved it. Here is the error I am getting:

```py
----------------------
1950
-----------------------
['/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-1-1950 todate: 31-1-1950', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-2-1950 todate: 28-2-1950', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-3-1950 todate: 31-3-1950', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-4-1950 todate: 30-4-1950', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-5-1950 todate: 31-5-1950', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-6-1950 todate: 30-6-1950', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-7-1950 todate: 31-7-1950', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-8-1950 todate: 31-8-1950', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-9-1950 todate: 30-9-1950', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-10-1950 todate: 31-10-1950', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-11-1950 todate: 30-11-1950', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-12-1950 todate: 31-12-1950']
----------------------
1951
-----------------------
['/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-1-1951 todate: 31-1-1951', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-2-1951 todate: 28-2-1951', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-3-1951 todate: 31-3-1951', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-4-1951 todate: 30-4-1951', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-5-1951 todate: 31-5-1951', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-6-1951 todate: 30-6-1951', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-7-1951 todate: 31-7-1951', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-8-1951 todate: 31-8-1951', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-9-1951 todate: 30-9-1951', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-10-1951 todate: 31-10-1951', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-11-1951 todate: 30-11-1951', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-12-1951 todate: 31-12-1951']
----------------------
1952
-----------------------
['/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-1-1952 todate: 31-1-1952', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-2-1952 todate: 29-2-1952', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-3-1952 todate: 31-3-1952', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-4-1952 todate: 30-4-1952', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-5-1952 todate: 31-5-1952', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-6-1952 todate: 30-6-1952', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-7-1952 todate: 31-7-1952', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-8-1952 todate: 31-8-1952', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-9-1952 todate: 30-9-1952', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-10-1952 todate: 31-10-1952', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-11-1952 todate: 30-11-1952', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-12-1952 todate: 31-12-1952']
----------------------
1953
-----------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
timeout                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    375         try:
--> 376             self._validate_conn(conn)
    377         except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError) as e:

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _validate_conn(self, conn)
    993         if not getattr(conn, "sock", None):  # AppEngine might not have  `.sock`
--> 994             conn.connect()
    995 

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py in connect(self)
    393             server_hostname=server_hostname,
--> 394             ssl_context=context,
    395         )

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py in ssl_wrap_socket(sock, keyfile, certfile, cert_reqs, ca_certs, server_hostname, ssl_version, ciphers, ssl_context, ca_cert_dir, key_password)
    369         if HAS_SNI and server_hostname is not None:
--> 370             return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
    371 

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/ssl.py in wrap_socket(self, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect, suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname, session)
    411             context=self,
--> 412             session=session
    413         )

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/ssl.py in _create(cls, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect, suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname, context, session)
    852                         raise ValueError("do_handshake_on_connect should not be specified for non-blocking sockets")
--> 853                     self.do_handshake()
    854             except (OSError, ValueError):

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/ssl.py in do_handshake(self, block)
   1116                 self.settimeout(None)
-> 1117             self._sslobj.do_handshake()
   1118         finally:

timeout: _ssl.c:1039: The handshake operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ReadTimeoutError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    448                     retries=self.max_retries,
--> 449                     timeout=timeout
    450                 )

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    719             retries = retries.increment(
--> 720                 method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
    721             )

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py in increment(self, method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)
    399             if read is False or not self._is_method_retryable(method):
--> 400                 raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
    401             elif read is not None:

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py in reraise(tp, value, tb)
    734                 raise value.with_traceback(tb)
--> 735             raise value
    736         finally:

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    671                 headers=headers,
--> 672                 chunked=chunked,
    673             )

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    378             # Py2 raises this as a BaseSSLError, Py3 raises it as socket timeout.
--> 379             self._raise_timeout(err=e, url=url, timeout_value=conn.timeout)
    380             raise

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _raise_timeout(self, err, url, timeout_value)
    330             raise ReadTimeoutError(
--> 331                 self, url, "Read timed out. (read timeout=%s)" % timeout_value
    332             )

ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='indiankanoon.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=5)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ReadTimeout                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-ef31c3cbb243> in <module>
      5     print('-----------------------')
      6 #     , headers = headers,timeout = 60headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36'}
----> 7     x = requests.get("https://indiankanoon.org/browse/supremecourt/%s/"%(i), timeout = 5)
      8     soup = BeautifulSoup(x.content, 'html.parser')
      9     data = [x["href"] for x in soup.find_all('a',{'href': re.compile(r'/search/')})]

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py in get(url, params, **kwargs)
     73 
     74     kwargs.setdefault('allow_redirects', True)
---> 75     return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
     76 
     77 

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py in request(method, url, **kwargs)
     58     # cases, and look like a memory leak in others.
     59     with sessions.Session() as session:
---> 60         return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
     61 
     62 

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    531         }
    532         send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 533         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    534 
    535         return resp

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    644 
    645         # Send the request
--> 646         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    647 
    648         # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    527                 raise SSLError(e, request=request)
    528             elif isinstance(e, ReadTimeoutError):
--> 529                 raise ReadTimeout(e, request=request)
    530             else:
    531                 raise

ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='indiankanoon.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=5)
```

As we can see it returns some results correctly (3 of them in this case) but then returns the error. I have tried increasing `timeout` to `60` but this has had no effects. Can anyone show me how to solve it?

Comment: Try waiting sometime between requests. Maybe you are fetching the urls too fast and that triggers some kind of "protection" on the server side ?

Comment: Another thing to try is to start after 1953, maybe that year triggers some bug on the server side? Does starting on any year produces a timeout after three requests?

Comment: No. It randomly stops at any year. The above-mentioned example is of 1953 but it has stopped working on several different years. Do you think I should use something like sleep?

Comment: Try to sleep several seconds between requests, it might work?

Comment: I tried to sleep for 10 seconds but that yielded no result. Any other way?

Comment: If the error is random, why don't you cache the results locally after each request and keep trying the years that give you an error until you have all years' results collected? After that you can process the data separately, with another script.

Comment: I did think of that but is a bit inefficient since currently, it works without a glitch for about 5 years, so will have to do it more than 10 times. Wanted to see if there is a solution to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively You can use Try..exception block.If timeout error comes it will print for that and move to next year and continue the loop.To avoid certificate issue I have used `verify=False`

Here is the code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
all_data=[]
for i in range(1950,2020):
  print(i)
  try:
    x = requests.get("https://indiankanoon.org/browse/supremecourt/%s/"%(i), timeout =10 ,verify=False)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(x.content, 'html.parser')
    data = [x["href"] for x in soup.find_all('a',{'href': re.compile(r'/search/')})]
    print(data)
    all_data.append(data)

  except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
      print("Timeout occurred")

print(all_data)
```

Here is output on console.

```
1950
C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:851: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
['/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-1-1950 todate: 31-1-1950', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-2-1950 todate: 28-2-1950', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-3-1950 todate: 31-3-1950', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-4-1950 todate: 30-4-1950', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-5-1950 todate: 31-5-1950', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-6-1950 todate: 30-6-1950', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-7-1950 todate: 31-7-1950', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-8-1950 todate: 31-8-1950', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-9-1950 todate: 30-9-1950', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-10-1950 todate: 31-10-1950', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-11-1950 todate: 30-11-1950', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-12-1950 todate: 31-12-1950']
1951
C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:851: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
['/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-1-1951 todate: 31-1-1951', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-2-1951 todate: 28-2-1951', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-3-1951 todate: 31-3-1951', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-4-1951 todate: 30-4-1951', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-5-1951 todate: 31-5-1951', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-6-1951 todate: 30-6-1951', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-7-1951 todate: 31-7-1951', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-8-1951 todate: 31-8-1951', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-9-1951 todate: 30-9-1951', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-10-1951 todate: 31-10-1951', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-11-1951 todate: 30-11-1951', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-12-1951 todate: 31-12-1951']
1952
C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:851: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
['/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-1-1952 todate: 31-1-1952', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-2-1952 todate: 29-2-1952', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-3-1952 todate: 31-3-1952', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-4-1952 todate: 30-4-1952', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-5-1952 todate: 31-5-1952', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-6-1952 todate: 30-6-1952', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-7-1952 todate: 31-7-1952', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-8-1952 todate: 31-8-1952', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-9-1952 todate: 30-9-1952', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-10-1952 todate: 31-10-1952', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-11-1952 todate: 30-11-1952', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-12-1952 todate: 31-12-1952']
1953
C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:851: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
['/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-1-1953 todate: 31-1-1953', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-2-1953 todate: 28-2-1953', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-3-1953 todate: 31-3-1953', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-4-1953 todate: 30-4-1953', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-5-1953 todate: 31-5-1953', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-6-1953 todate: 30-6-1953', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-7-1953 todate: 31-7-1953', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-8-1953 todate: 31-8-1953', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-9-1953 todate: 30-9-1953', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-10-1953 todate: 31-10-1953', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-11-1953 todate: 30-11-1953', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-12-1953 todate: 31-12-1953']
1954
C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:851: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
['/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-1-1954 todate: 31-1-1954', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-2-1954 todate: 28-2-1954', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-3-1954 todate: 31-3-1954', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-4-1954 todate: 30-4-1954', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-5-1954 todate: 31-5-1954', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-6-1954 todate: 30-6-1954', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-7-1954 todate: 31-7-1954', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-8-1954 todate: 31-8-1954', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-9-1954 todate: 30-9-1954', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-10-1954 todate: 31-10-1954', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-11-1954 todate: 30-11-1954', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-12-1954 todate: 31-12-1954']
1955
C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:851: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
['/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-1-1955 todate: 31-1-1955', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-2-1955 todate: 28-2-1955', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-3-1955 todate: 31-3-1955', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-4-1955 todate: 30-4-1955', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-5-1955 todate: 31-5-1955', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-6-1955 todate: 30-6-1955', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-7-1955 todate: 31-7-1955', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-8-1955 todate: 31-8-1955', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-9-1955 todate: 30-9-1955', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-10-1955 todate: 31-10-1955', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-11-1955 todate: 30-11-1955', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-12-1955 todate: 31-12-1955']
1956
C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:851: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
['/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-1-1956 todate: 31-1-1956', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-2-1956 todate: 29-2-1956', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-3-1956 todate: 31-3-1956', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-4-1956 todate: 30-4-1956', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-5-1956 todate: 31-5-1956', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-6-1956 todate: 30-6-1956', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-7-1956 todate: 31-7-1956', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-8-1956 todate: 31-8-1956', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-9-1956 todate: 30-9-1956', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-10-1956 todate: 31-10-1956', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-11-1956 todate: 30-11-1956', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-12-1956 todate: 31-12-1956']
1957
C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:851: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
['/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-1-1957 todate: 31-1-1957', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-2-1957 todate: 28-2-1957', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-3-1957 todate: 31-3-1957', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-4-1957 todate: 30-4-1957', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-5-1957 todate: 31-5-1957', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-6-1957 todate: 30-6-1957', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-7-1957 todate: 31-7-1957', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-8-1957 todate: 31-8-1957', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-9-1957 todate: 30-9-1957', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-10-1957 todate: 31-10-1957', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-11-1957 todate: 30-11-1957', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-12-1957 todate: 31-12-1957']
1958
C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:851: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
['/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-1-1958 todate: 31-1-1958', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-2-1958 todate: 28-2-1958', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-3-1958 todate: 31-3-1958', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-4-1958 todate: 30-4-1958', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-5-1958 todate: 31-5-1958', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-6-1958 todate: 30-6-1958', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-7-1958 todate: 31-7-1958', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-8-1958 todate: 31-8-1958', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-9-1958 todate: 30-9-1958', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-10-1958 todate: 31-10-1958', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-11-1958 todate: 30-11-1958', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-12-1958 todate: 31-12-1958']
1959
C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:851: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
['/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-1-1959 todate: 31-1-1959', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-2-1959 todate: 28-2-1959', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-3-1959 todate: 31-3-1959', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-4-1959 todate: 30-4-1959', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-5-1959 todate: 31-5-1959', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-6-1959 todate: 30-6-1959', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-7-1959 todate: 31-7-1959', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-8-1959 todate: 31-8-1959', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-9-1959 todate: 30-9-1959', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-10-1959 todate: 31-10-1959', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-11-1959 todate: 30-11-1959', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-12-1959 todate: 31-12-1959']
1960
C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:851: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
['/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-1-1960 todate: 31-1-1960', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-2-1960 todate: 29-2-1960', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-3-1960 todate: 31-3-1960', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-4-1960 todate: 30-4-1960', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-5-1960 todate: 31-5-1960', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-6-1960 todate: 30-6-1960', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-7-1960 todate: 31-7-1960', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-8-1960 todate: 31-8-1960', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-9-1960 todate: 30-9-1960', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-10-1960 todate: 31-10-1960', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-11-1960 todate: 30-11-1960', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-12-1960 todate: 31-12-1960']
1961
C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:851: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
['/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-1-1961 todate: 31-1-1961', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-2-1961 todate: 28-2-1961', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-3-1961 todate: 31-3-1961', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-4-1961 todate: 30-4-1961', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-5-1961 todate: 31-5-1961', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-6-1961 todate: 30-6-1961', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-7-1961 todate: 31-7-1961', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-8-1961 todate: 31-8-1961', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-9-1961 todate: 30-9-1961', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-10-1961 todate: 31-10-1961', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-11-1961 todate: 30-11-1961', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-12-1961 todate: 31-12-1961']
1962
C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:851: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
['/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-1-1962 todate: 31-1-1962', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-2-1962 todate: 28-2-1962', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-3-1962 todate: 31-3-1962', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-4-1962 todate: 30-4-1962', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-5-1962 todate: 31-5-1962', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-6-1962 todate: 30-6-1962', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-7-1962 todate: 31-7-1962', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-8-1962 todate: 31-8-1962', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-9-1962 todate: 30-9-1962', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-10-1962 todate: 31-10-1962', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-11-1962 todate: 30-11-1962', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-12-1962 todate: 31-12-1962']
1963
C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:851: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
['/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-1-1963 todate: 31-1-1963', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-2-1963 todate: 28-2-1963', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-3-1963 todate: 31-3-1963', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-4-1963 todate: 30-4-1963', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-5-1963 todate: 31-5-1963', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-6-1963 todate: 30-6-1963', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-7-1963 todate: 31-7-1963', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-8-1963 todate: 31-8-1963', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-9-1963 todate: 30-9-1963', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-10-1963 todate: 31-10-1963', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-11-1963 todate: 30-11-1963', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-12-1963 todate: 31-12-1963']
1964
C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:851: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
['/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-1-1964 todate: 31-1-1964', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-2-1964 todate: 29-2-1964', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-3-1964 todate: 31-3-1964', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-4-1964 todate: 30-4-1964', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-5-1964 todate: 31-5-1964', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-6-1964 todate: 30-6-1964', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-7-1964 todate: 31-7-1964', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-8-1964 todate: 31-8-1964', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-9-1964 todate: 30-9-1964', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-10-1964 todate: 31-10-1964', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-11-1964 todate: 30-11-1964', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-12-1964 todate: 31-12-1964']
1965
C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:851: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
['/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-1-1965 todate: 31-1-1965', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-2-1965 todate: 28-2-1965', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-3-1965 todate: 31-3-1965', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-4-1965 todate: 30-4-1965', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-5-1965 todate: 31-5-1965', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-6-1965 todate: 30-6-1965', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-7-1965 todate: 31-7-1965', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-8-1965 todate: 31-8-1965', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-9-1965 todate: 30-9-1965', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-10-1965 todate: 31-10-1965', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-11-1965 todate: 30-11-1965', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-12-1965 todate: 31-12-1965']
1966
C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:851: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
['/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-1-1966 todate: 31-1-1966', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-2-1966 todate: 28-2-1966', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-3-1966 todate: 31-3-1966', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-4-1966 todate: 30-4-1966', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-5-1966 todate: 31-5-1966', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-6-1966 todate: 30-6-1966', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-7-1966 todate: 31-7-1966', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-8-1966 todate: 31-8-1966', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-9-1966 todate: 30-9-1966', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-10-1966 todate: 31-10-1966', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-11-1966 todate: 30-11-1966', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-12-1966 todate: 31-12-1966']
1967
C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:851: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
['/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-1-1967 todate: 31-1-1967', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-2-1967 todate: 28-2-1967', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-3-1967 todate: 31-3-1967', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-4-1967 todate: 30-4-1967', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-5-1967 todate: 31-5-1967', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-6-1967 todate: 30-6-1967', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-7-1967 todate: 31-7-1967', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-8-1967 todate: 31-8-1967', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-9-1967 todate: 30-9-1967', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-10-1967 todate: 31-10-1967', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-11-1967 todate: 30-11-1967', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-12-1967 todate: 31-12-1967']
1968
C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:851: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
['/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-1-1968 todate: 31-1-1968', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-2-1968 todate: 29-2-1968', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-3-1968 todate: 31-3-1968', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-4-1968 todate: 30-4-1968', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-5-1968 todate: 31-5-1968', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-6-1968 todate: 30-6-1968', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-7-1968 todate: 31-7-1968', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-8-1968 todate: 31-8-1968', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-9-1968 todate: 30-9-1968', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-10-1968 todate: 31-10-1968', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-11-1968 todate: 30-11-1968', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-12-1968 todate: 31-12-1968']
1969
C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:851: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
['/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-1-1969 todate: 31-1-1969', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-2-1969 todate: 28-2-1969', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-3-1969 todate: 31-3-1969', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-4-1969 todate: 30-4-1969', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-5-1969 todate: 31-5-1969', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-6-1969 todate: 30-6-1969', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-7-1969 todate: 31-7-1969', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-8-1969 todate: 31-8-1969', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-9-1969 todate: 30-9-1969', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-10-1969 todate: 31-10-1969', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-11-1969 todate: 30-11-1969', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-12-1969 todate: 31-12-1969']
1970
C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:851: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
['/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-1-1970 todate: 31-1-1970', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-2-1970 todate: 28-2-1970', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-3-1970 todate: 31-3-1970', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-4-1970 todate: 30-4-1970', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-5-1970 todate: 31-5-1970', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-6-1970 todate: 30-6-1970', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-7-1970 todate: 31-7-1970', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-8-1970 todate: 31-8-1970', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-9-1970 todate: 30-9-1970', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-10-1970 todate: 31-10-1970', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-11-1970 todate: 30-11-1970', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-12-1970 todate: 31-12-1970']
1971
C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:851: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
['/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-1-1971 todate: 31-1-1971', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-2-1971 todate: 28-2-1971', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-3-1971 todate: 31-3-1971', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-4-1971 todate: 30-4-1971', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-5-1971 todate: 31-5-1971', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-6-1971 todate: 30-6-1971', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-7-1971 todate: 31-7-1971', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-8-1971 todate: 31-8-1971', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-9-1971 todate: 30-9-1971', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-10-1971 todate: 31-10-1971', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-11-1971 todate: 30-11-1971', '/search/?formInput=doctypes:supremecourt fromdate:1-12-1971 todate: 31-12-1971']
```

And so on....

Comment: that's also can be handled via asynco for waiting.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη : Well there are many options available.It would be great if you post an answer using asynco.

Comment: that's has been left for you prince :P

Comment: we both should. haha

Comment: I marked this as the correct answer as it provided a concrete solution and not a bandaid one like the other answers. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

try `time.sleep(2)` between requests, it seems to be solving it indeed

Comment: Please look at my comment. I have tried it for 10 seconds but it still seems to not work.

Comment: Hi Zohra, I tried ```sleep(4)``` and it did not work but when I tried ```time.sleep(4)``` it worked! Thanks.

Comment: Wonder why this is happening?

Comment: you're welcome, I only know the `sleep()` that is defined under the time module to be honest.