# Python - create stateful connection with website and get data after X seconds

Tags: python, url, python-requests

I have a website that once you entered, it's starting a timer of 5 seconds and randomly enters a number to the screen. I want to open the URL with python and get the number after 5 seconds. It's not possible with `requests` because python ends the connection as soon as it starts. Any ideas?

Comment: This question is impossible to answer without knowing how the site actually works. If it is using javascript, for example, the way to achieve this will be using a selenium-based solution (or any other way that supports javascript execution)

Comment: Will it be helpful to send you the URL? I'm not sure if it does

Answer (score 0):

If you know how the site functions, you can either use selenium or build a web scraper using Beautifulsoup
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implementing-web-scraping-python-beautiful-soup/

And see this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59304608/how-to-solve-timed-out-error-when-using-requests-with-beautifulsoup)